# Base64 encode percent sign and equal sign issue

Tags: angular, base64, .net-5

I encode same string at both web api(.net core) and typscript side.

My string : /companyName/companyId

Encoded by web api : **/UVJPTEVTIGluYw==/OTA=/**

Encoded by client side : **/UVJPTEVTIGluYw%3D%3D/OTA%3D/**

So, these strings doesnt match. What is the reason for the difference between the equal sign and the percent sign? How do I overcome this problem?

I used;

`btoa` on client side

```
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

on web api side.

Comment: It's clear from your example that you're not encoding the full URL at once because a base 64 string can't contain slashes, but rather you're converting each part of the URL independently, then joining then to form a new URL. Can you show us your actual code?

Answer (score 0):

If it comes from web it can have %0A (URL encoding) instead of \n (C encoding).

Had issue with decoding of the bitmap on Java side.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP